# How to access environment variables from Node app client

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Node app deployed to Elastic Beanstalk. I have javascript that runs client-side to make HTTP requests. The client-side javascript refers to routes that have the port hard-coded in the URI.

Elastic Beanstalk listens on port 8081. In my app.js file, I can write `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000` and that works just fine (because this runs server-side).

The difficulty I'm having is in my client-side javascript. Suppose I have something like this

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/users/login', {...})
```

To run on Elastic Beanstalk, I need to change this to 8081, but if I try to make it dynamic as in app.js, the `process` variable isn't found. Concretely, if I change the route to

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000 
fetch('http://localhost:' + port + '/users/login', {...})
```

then I get the following error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process`.

I think I understand the crux of the problem (the environment variables are only available on the server), but I'm a Node/Express noob, and I'm not sure what the best way is to access the PORT environment variable on the client.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `webpack` to bundle your FE application, you can configure your application to pass along the environment variables to the FE application.

This [blog](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-include-environment-variables-in-your-react-app-e4657c178b5c) describes how it's done when using `create react app`. On inspecting the webpack config, two functions which essentially do the trick are:

```
function getClientEnvironment () {
  const raw = Object.keys(process.env)
    // Custom regex to allow only a certain category of variables available to the application
    .filter(<restrict the variables available to the application>)
    .reduce(
      (env, key) => {
        env[key] = process.env[key];
        return env;
      },
      {
        NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
      }
    );
  // Stringify all values so we can feed into Webpack DefinePlugin
  const stringified = {
    'process.env': Object.keys(raw).reduce((env, key) => {
      env[key] = JSON.stringify(raw[key]);
      return env;
    }, {}),
  };

  return { raw, stringified };
}
```

```
const env = getClientEnvironment()
```

And in your webpack configuration page, you could add these to the `plugins` section of webpack config:

```
new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified)
```

This will allow you to access the variables in `js` as

```
process.env.<VARIABLE NAME>
```

and in `HTML` as:

```
%<VARIABLE NAME>%
```